# Is a Stored Procedure required when we invoke 2 or 3 inline db queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, stored-procedures

I am working on a new application.For some of the functionality I have to query the db multiple times and based on the query result I do some other update or insert. So in one case I query the db 3 times for a user action.

Ex :

1)select from table **X** 2)if 1 returns a non empty result set then Insert into table **Y**  3) Insert into table **Z** using the auto generated ID from the 2nd step.

In some cases there are only 2 steps.For these kind of scenarios is it necessary to have a stored procedure to avoid the multiple round trip time to the database.Will there be a performance impact assuming the application is a new one and the users would be very small.

Or is inline sql fine ?

Comment: They both sound fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make 3 calls to the database. Make 1 call with 3 statements separated by semi-colon.

In my opinion, if the stored proc is not being used by other applications. I would rather have it in the application, so not to pollute the database and have one place to find all the code.

Comment: I didnot get you.After the 1st select statement I have to check some condition and then if its positive then do the second db insert.With the auto generated from the second insert statement I have to do a 3rd insert in other table.We cannot do all this in one Query? I was just checking if 2 or 3 queries to a db would have any performance impact(for a new application) considering the round trip time.

Comment: If you can do it in stored proc, you can do it inline. Essentially, send the content of your stored proc in the call, including IF statements.

Comment: ok.Though technically its possible,it would be error prone to manually create the 3 statements including the if else.In that case it would be better to go for an SP. btw I was looking to find if inline sql queries would pose any performance impact because of the round trip or if that would be negligible.

Comment: There definitely will be latency because the two apps (yours and MySQL) has to talk to each other between round-trips. If this an online app your wouldn't notice it, but if suddenly decide to send a batch of UPSERT you might see noticeable difference.